# How can I authenticate a backend service against my AWS Api Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a lambda function running behind the aws api gateway, that acts as the backend for my website. It uses a cognito authorizer to authenticate the users of my website. This works fine.

Now I need to authenticate a c# backend service against the api that is not running in the cloud has no user interaction. It should just synchronize data.

My initial plan was to configure cognito credentials and log into the cloud via the cognito sdk but this is not possible as the app would then need developer access to my cloud.

I also thought about using the api gateway api keys but I would still need the cognito authentication then.

So how can I authenticate my c# service against my aws api without user interaction being nessecary?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Cognito User Pool Authentication.

This is an OpenID implementation where Cognito issues JSON Web Tokens (JWTs) where the signature of a JWT can be verified with a public endpoint.

In the context of API Gateway, you would use a Lambda as a custom authorizer, but the tokens could be verified in any environment/language with a relevant JWT Library.

More reading: [Verifying a JWT issued by Cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html)